# Perl Net::LDAPS SSL version negotiation

Tags: perl, ssl, ldap

### Platform

- OS: RHEL 5.4
- Perl: 5.8.8
- OpenSSL: 0.9.8e
- Net::LDAP: 0.33

### Details

We have a perl script which monitors LDAP servers used by our application and sends alerts if these are not reachable or functional in some way. On the whole this works well except for a particular LDAP server which is only accepting SSLv2. The LDAP object creation looks as follows

```
my $current_server = Net::LDAP->new('ldaps://10.1.1.1:636/,
                     verify => 'none',
                     sslversion => 'sslv23',
                     timeout => 30 )
```

Notice *sslv23*, which according to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.49/lib/Net/LDAP.pod), allows SSLv2 or 3 to be used. The relevant entry in the docs is

> sslversion => 'sslv2' | 'sslv3' | 'sslv23' | 'tlsv1'

However, the above does not work. When I change the "sslversion" to be "sslv2" then the script *does* work.

### Conclusion

How can I get Net::LDAPS to retry with sslv2 if sslv3 does not work?

Thanks,

Fred.

Comment: Have you tried something like `my $server = Net::LDAP->new(..., sslversion => 'sslv23') || Net::LDAP->new(..., sslversion => 'sslv2')`?

Comment: @Moritz Yes, I have set it to "sslv2" and then it works. But I don't want to limit the script to only use SSLv2 since some servers might be only SSLv3. It would be great if Net::LDAP could negotiate a workable SSL version and use it. Otherwise I can always try v3 first and fall back to v2 within my script but that seems like something the library should do.

Comment: What I meant: try connecting with the standard string first, if that fails try connecting again -- by simply constructing a second `Net::LDAP` object. Yes, this is a workaround.

Comment: Are you really sure your LDAP server only accepts SSLv2 connection? How ancient is it?

Comment: It is a customer server over which we have no control and empirical evidence suggests it does not support sslv3. So, unfortunately, I've no choice in this regard.

Comment: @FredClausen, would it be because it only supports TLS 1.0 or above instead?

Comment: @Bruno I'll test some TLS options - I was only looking at SSL to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - I could not find a way to make the library fall back to SSLv2 if SSLv3 fails so I did that in my own code by first trying SSLv3 and, if that fails, SSLv2. This works for my specific situation.

I encourage anyone who has more information to comment.

Answer (score 0):

- Which version of `IO::Socket::SSL` are you using?
- Which version of `Net::SSLeay` are you using?

If you look at the [source code for `IO::Socket::SSL`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-2.012/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm), you will see that `sslv23` means it will use `Net::SSLeay::CTX_new()` which is equivalent to `Net::SSLeay::CTX_v23_new()`. `SSLv2` may have been dropped from your library's `CTX_v23_new` implementation.